# How to update value of a <td> present under table

Tags: jquery

Currently the **SNO** column is of type element ( input type text ).
Is it possible to have same look as of like  Company column

I have tried as

```
  var orderid = 'order_' + incrementi;
                html += '<tr id=' + incrementi + '  company_id=' + company_id + ' style="cursor: move;">\
      <td id=' + orderid + '  style="vertical-align: middle;">' +  incrementi  + '</td>\n\
             <td style="vertical-align: middle;">' + company_name + '</td>\n\
             <td style="vertical-align: middle;">' + company_author + '</td>\n\
            </tr>'
```

But the issue i am facing **in the callback function which is called when drag is done**

```
$("#sort tbody").on("sortupdate", function(event, ui)
{
        $('#sort tbody tr').each(function()
        {
                var tr_id = $(this).attr('id');
                $("#order_" + tr_id).val($(this).index() + 1)
        });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/z74VH/17/

Comment: it is working fine in fiddle. what you want?

Comment: SNO should be normal <td> instead of a input type text element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace the input element with plain text and apply the id to the **SNO** `td`. Then change the `sortupdate` event to update the `td` text instead of the input value:

```
function allPacsDisplayHTML()
{
        var information = response.pacs_order_of_dispaly;
        var html = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < information.length; i++)
        {
                var company_id = information[i].company_id;
                var orderdp = information[i].order_of_display;
                var company_name = information[i].company_name;
                var company_author = information[i].company_author;
                var incrementi = i + 1;
                var orderid = 'order_' + incrementi;
                html += '<tr id="' + incrementi + '"  company_id="' + company_id + '" style="cursor: move;">\
             <td style="vertical-align: middle;" id="'+orderid+'">'+incrementi+'</td>\n\
             <td style="vertical-align: middle;">' + company_name + '</td>\n\
             <td style="vertical-align: middle;">' + company_author + '</td>\n\
            </tr>'
        }
        $("#sort tbody").html(html);
}

$("#sort tbody").on("sortupdate", function(event, ui)
{
        $('#sort tbody tr').each(function()
        {
                var tr_id = $(this).attr('id');
                $("#order_" + tr_id).text($(this).index() + 1);
        });
});
```

Check this updated [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ugxjsnhL/).

Comment: Yes, that's the case. But you should also remove the `input` element and apply the **id** to the `td` element

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you need to remove your input element and apply id on td element instead.

Change your SNO td and apply order id to it as follows,

```
<td id=" + orderid + ">' + incrementi + '</td>\n\
```

Then in jQuery set value on that td,

```
$('#sort tbody tr').each(function()
        {
                var tr_id = $(this).attr('id');
                $("td#order_" + tr_id).html($(this).index() + 1)
        });
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/z74VH/19/